# How spark RangeBetween works with Descending Order?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I thought rangeBetween(start, end) looks into values of the range(cur_value - start, cur_value + end). https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/WindowSpec.html

But, I saw an example where they used descending orderBy() on timestamp, and then used (unboundedPreceeding, 0) with rangeBetween. Which led me to explore the following example:

```
dd = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, "a"), (3, "a"), (3, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "b"), (3, "b")],
    ['id', 'category']
)
dd.show()

# output
+---+--------+
| id|category|
+---+--------+
|  1|       a|
|  3|       a|
|  3|       a|
|  1|       b|
|  2|       b|
|  3|       b|
+---+--------+
```

It seems to include preceding row whose value is higher by 1.

```
byCategoryOrderedById = Window.partitionBy('category')\
                              .orderBy(desc('id'))\
                              .rangeBetween(-1, Window.currentRow)
dd.withColumn("sum", Fsum('id').over(byCategoryOrderedById)).show()

# output
+---+--------+---+
| id|category|sum|
+---+--------+---+
|  3|       b|  3|
|  2|       b|  5|
|  1|       b|  3|
|  3|       a|  6|
|  3|       a|  6|
|  1|       a|  1|
+---+--------+---+
```

And with start set to -2, it includes value greater by 2 but in preceding rows.

```
byCategoryOrderedById = Window.partitionBy('category')\
                        .orderBy(desc('id'))\
                        .rangeBetween(-2,Window.currentRow)
dd.withColumn("sum", Fsum('id').over(byCategoryOrderedById)).show()

# output
+---+--------+---+
| id|category|sum|
+---+--------+---+
|  3|       b|  3|
|  2|       b|  5|
|  1|       b|  6|
|  3|       a|  6|
|  3|       a|  6|
|  1|       a|  7|
+---+--------+---+
```

So, what is the exact behavior of rangeBetween with desc orderBy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not well documented but when using range (or value-based) frames the ascending and descending order affects the determination of the values that are included in the frame.

Let's take the example you provided:

```
RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
```

Depending on the order by direction, `1 PRECEDING` means:

- current_row_value - 1 if ASC
- current_row_value + 1 if DESC

Consider the row with value 1 in partition `b`.

- With the descending order, the frame includes :

  `(current_value and all preceding values where x = current_value + 1) = (1, 2)`
- With the ascending order, the frame includes:

  `(current_value and all preceding values where x = current_value - 1) = (1)`

**PS:** using `rangeBetween(-1, Window.currentRow)` with desc ordering is just equivalent to  `rangeBetween(Window.currentRow, 1)` with asc ordering.